# Basic Food Bank program help needed

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array

I'm having an issue in the code below for option 2 which is the request. Each time I print out the request table, instead of it showing the pending requests inputted by the user, it gives me a random high number. Can someone help me find the issue? The code should be similar to option 1, but it shouldn't add up the user inputs if its the same request. Example Output:

```
1
Milk 20
1
Milk 20
2
Milk 10
2
Milk 5
4
Donations: 
Milk 40
Requests: 
Milk 10
Milk 5
```

This is my code

```
int main() {

int don_count=0, don_amt[100], found, i, don_quant, option, req_count=0, req_amt[100],req_quant;

char word[20], don_inv_type[100][20], req_word[20], req_inv_type[100][20];

printf("Welcome to the food bank program!);
printf("1.Enter a Donation\n2.Enter a Request\n3.Fulfill the earliest Request\n4.Print status report\n5.Exit\n");
scanf("%d", &option);

while (option != 5) {

      // Execute a deposit.
      if (option == 1) {
                 scanf ("%s", word);
                 scanf ("%d", &don_quant);
                 found = -99;
                 for (i=0;i<don_count; i++){
                     if (strcmp(don_inv_type[i], word)==0)
                     found = i;
                     }
                 if (found == -99){
                               strcpy(don_inv_type[i],word);
                               don_amt[i] = don_quant;
                               don_count ++;
                               }
                 else
                         don_amt[found] += don_quant;
      }

      else if (option == 2) {
           scanf ("%s", req_word);
           scanf ("%d", &req_quant);
           req_count++;
           for(i=0; i<req_count; i++)
           {
                    strcpy(req_inv_type[i],req_word);
                    req_amt[i] += req_quant;
           }
      }

      else if (option == 3) {


      }

      else if (option == 4) {
           printf("Donations:\n");
           for(i=0;i<don_count;i++){
                                    printf("%8s", don_inv_type[i]);
                                    printf("%5d\n", don_amt[i]);
                                    }
           printf("Requests: \n");
           for(i=0;i<req_count;i++){
                                    printf("%8s", req_inv_type[i]);
                                    printf("%5d\n", req_amt[i]);
                                    }


      }

      else if (option == 5) {
           printf(" Thanks bye");     

      }

      // Reprompt the menu.
      printf("1.Enter a Donation\n2.Enter a Request\n3.Fulfill the earliest Request\n4.Print status report\n5.Exit\n\n");
      scanf("%d", &option);
} // end while

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
} // end main
```

Comment: learn how to use debugger to debug your program.

Comment: @BryanChen - yeah, like that's gonna happen, ever:((

Comment: its an issue with the line that says req_amt[i] += req_quant;

Comment: the array is causing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialize `req_amt`, so `req_amt[i] += req_quant` is just adding `req_quant` to whatever garbage was at those memory locations previously.

You need to do something like:

```
int req_amt[100] = {0};
                ^^^^^^  <--- Add this
```

or to manually initialize the elements in some other way.

Comment: thanks that helped with the huge number error, but now whenever input another item amount in the que, say the first input was 5 then the second input is 10. It prints saying Milk 15  Milk 10, instead of Milk 5 then Milk 10

Comment: @Tristen: Then you have a separate question, so you can post it separately to Stack Overflow if you want. However, I'd recommend spending some time debugging it, first - it's not generally considered acceptable to serially post questions about each successive error you get in the same program, as it comes across as you wanting someone else to debug your program for you.